# Use car speaker output as input to IC?

Tags: transformer, converter

I have a circuit that is to be used together with a car stereo. The circuit detects DTMF tones (touch tones) using the Holtek HT9170B.

I need to feed the HT9170B with the high level speaker output from the car stereo so that any DTMF tone (dialed with the internal car telephone) is recognised by my circuit.

The HT9170B has an op-amp input, the standard input circuit is shown below. The input voltage is -0.3V to +0.3V.

[image]

I was thinking of using a line out converter with a load resistor and transformer as described at http://www.bcae1.com/loc.htm, but will this be sufficient?

Can anyone suggest a cheap transformer to use for this purpose?

Comment: How about just using a microphone to pick up the DTMF?

Comment: I don't have any processing power available to determine the tone if a mic is used.

Comment: Does not compute?

Comment: Sorry, bad explanation of me. Using a mic is unfortunately not an alternative.

Comment: Your processor will work the same if a mic or a direct line in is used...

Comment: I misunderstood Andy akas suggestion. I thought the suggestion was to use a mic input directly to the processor, eliminating the DTMF ic. But using a mic as input to the DTMF ic is unfortunately not an option, I have to feed the signal directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your car amp likely has a bridged output so I would use a transformer since you likely want a grounded circuit around the holtec.I think your bigger problem is the dynamic range of the amp's audio signal unless you never vary the volume control on the amp.

Comment: Yes, a transformer is the way to go. I have tested a similar setup with a standard line out converter with a transformer for each channel (from amazon). I tapped the car speaker wires, fed the signal through the line out converter and finally into a pc microphone input. This worked well on all volumes. But my concern is that the microphone input and the Holtek input is not similar, and that this direct approach cannot be used. Am I right?